# How to add number in feature method name in Spock framework

Tags: string, spock

I want to add serial numbers in the feature methods name in Spock framework. How can I do this?

A code snippet is given for clarification:

```
class Test extends Specification {

    static def count = 0;

    def setup() {
        count++
    }

    def '${count} This is first scenario'() {
        ...
    }

    def '${count} This is second scenario'() {
        ...
    }

}
```

After running this code, it shows in the report:

> ${count} This is first scenario
>
> ${count} This is second scenario

But I am expecting:

> 1 This is first scenario
>
> 2 This is second scenario

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
@Unroll
def "(#iterationIndex) test name" { ... }
```

**UPD:** it was called `#iterationCount` but now it is `#iterationIndex`, see https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M5/migration_guide.html

Comment: and iterationCount has to be present in where block, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's a built-in variable.

Comment: Will I increment this built-in variable in setup method or it will be incremented automatically?

Comment: Misunderstood your question. #iterationCount is for data-driven testing (example: http://meetspock.appspot.com/edit/5092402331123712). The feature you are asking for doesn't exist; perhaps a Spock extension could handle this (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

In `def '${count} This is first scenario'()` you are declaring a method. A method name can't be dynamically generated.

You can inject parameters of the test into a template in the method name, with data-driven tests and `@Unroll` but I don't think it's what you need.

An example, from the documentation :

```
@Unroll
def "maximum of #a and #b is #c"() { 
 expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c

    where:
    a | b || c
    3 | 5 || 5
    7 | 0 || 7
    0 | 0 || 0
}
```

Comment: Yes, injecting parameters is not what i want to do. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Share anotation with count and delete static modifier.

> You can indicate to Spock which objects you want to survive across all test methods by using the @Shared annotation.

Comment: It would be better if you added some code to your answer.